# local variable set to nil after switch-to-buffer call

Tags: frames, local-variables

Emacs 26.1 user here.

I know some common-lisp but new to elisp, so I wonder if I'm missing something obvious. I'm trying a rather simple frame setup with a function I wrote, and there's this strange behaviour. My local variable is getting set to nil after switch-to-buffer call. Here's the simplified version that has the same issue.

```lisp
(defun my-frame-test1 ()
  (let ((frame (make-frame '((name . "test-frame")
                             (width . 300)
                             (visibility . nil)
                             (height . 100))))
        left-window edit-window-left edit-window-right)
    (set-frame-position frame 100 100)
    (make-frame-visible frame)
    (select-frame frame)
    (setq-local left-window (selected-window))
    (setq-local edit-window-left (split-window-right 30))
    (select-window edit-window-left)
    (setq-local edit-window-right (split-window-right))
    ;; ---- edit-window-right has the expected value at this point ----

    (dolist (f '("/tmp/file1.lisp" "/tmp/file2.lisp"))
      (find-file-noselect f t))
    (switch-to-buffer (get-file-buffer "/tmp/file1.lisp")) ;; after this line, edit-window-right has changed to nil
    (select-window edit-window-right) ;; <-- thus, this call doesn't work.
    (switch-to-buffer (get-file-buffer "/tmp/file2.lisp"))
    ))
```

I tried using setq instead of a let block, using different variable name, for example 'amp-edit-window-right, calling (switch-to-buffer (get-file-buffer "/tmp/file1.lisp") nil t), and all behave the same.

When I do a line by line execution by using the new frame and M-: it is the same. And the window that edit-window-right is set to (#<window 18 on some-file.el>) still has the same print value after edit-window-right is set to nil (i.e. the same window still exists).

Why would this happen?

Comment: When you switch to the other buffer, it's likely put in some (major) mode. Every function that switches to a major mode calls `kill-all-local-variables`. See `C-h f` for that function.

Comment: I'm finding the question difficult to follow, but I think you're misunderstanding what the "local" in `setq-local` means, which is *buffer-local*.  If you set a buffer-local variable and then switch to a different buffer; in the new buffer you naturally won't see the value which was local to the original buffer.

Comment: @phils, I was also trying the same with setq instead of setq-locals, but you're right, I don't have enough grasp on variable scope for elisp.

Comment: I just tried defvars for the same variables and it works correctly. So @Drew, you are right, major mode is changing. Care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotating parts of your code:

```el
(let (left-window edit-window-left edit-window-right)
  ;; ^ these variables go out of scope at the end of the `let' form,
  ;;
  ;; If you were using `setq' below instead of `setq-local' then you would
  ;; be manipulating these values; but because you're setting buffer-local
  ;; values instead, these let-bound variables never change from their `nil'
  ;; default values.
  ;;
  ;; We are currently in some arbitrary buffer X.
  (setq-local left-window (selected-window))
  (setq-local edit-window-left (split-window-right 30))
  ;; ^ These values are local to buffer X.
  (select-window edit-window-left)
  (setq-local edit-window-right (split-window-right))
  ;; ^ This value is also local to buffer X (because `edit-window-left' is
  ;; still showing buffer X).
  (dolist (f '("/tmp/file1.lisp" "/tmp/file2.lisp"))
    (find-file-noselect f t))
  ;; ^ These are quite likely to be different buffers to X.
  (switch-to-buffer (get-file-buffer "/tmp/file1.lisp"))
  ;; ^ We can no longer see the values which were local to X
  ;; (unless this buffer was X), so we will see the `nil' values
  ;; from your `let' bindings.
  (select-window edit-window-right)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-file-buffer "/tmp/file2.lisp"))
  ;; ^ As before -- we probably see the `let' bound values in here.
  )
;; The `let' ends here, and so now *only* buffer X sees values for
;; `left-window', `edit-window-left', and `edit-window-right'.
```

Answer (score 4):

1. I'm guessing that you really want to use `setq`, not `setq-local` in that code.  Did you intend to set buffer-local values of those `let`-bound variables?

   As @phils points out, `setq-local` sets a buffer-local variable.  And the Elisp manual tells us, in node [Creating Buffer Local](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html):

> Making a variable buffer-local within a `let`-binding for that
> variable does not work reliably, unless the buffer in which you do
> this is not current either on entry to or exit from the `let`.
> This is because `let` does not distinguish between different kinds
> of bindings; it knows only which variable the binding was made for.

2. What's more, when you change the current buffer in that code by visiting a file, the buffer you switch to turns on a major mode, and that invokes `kill-all-local-variables`, which does this:

> `kill-all-local-variables` is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> `(kill-all-local-variables)`
>
> Switch to Fundamental mode by **killing current buffer's local variables**.
>
> Most local variable bindings are eliminated so that the default values
> become effective once more.  Also, the syntax table is set from
> `standard-syntax-table`, the local keymap is set to `nil`,
> and the abbrev table from `fundamental-mode-abbrev-table`.
> This function also forces redisplay of the mode line.
>
> **Every function to select a new major mode starts by
> calling this function.**
>
> As a special exception, local variables whose names have
> a non-`nil` `permanent-local` property are not eliminated by this function.
>
> The first thing this function does is run
> the normal hook `change-major-mode-hook`.

3. `setq-local` is really `set` applied to a buffer-local variable.
   `(setq-local foo bar)` macroexpands to `(set (make-local-variable 'foo) bar)`.
   So `setq-local` always applies to a *dynamic* binding.

   Node [Setting Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Variables.html) of the Elisp manual tells us:

> When dynamic variable binding is in effect (the default), `set` has
> the same effect as `setq`, apart from the fact that `set` evaluates
> its SYMBOL argument whereas `setq` does not.  But when a variable
> is lexically bound, `set` affects its *dynamic* value, whereas
> `setq` affects its current (lexical) value.  See [Variable Scoping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html).

Comment: For clarification (as the "when you change the current buffer in that code" part is a bit misleading) it's the `find-file-noselect` process which sets the major mode for those buffers in that code, not the `switch-to-buffer`.

Comment: @phils: Yes, you're right. Visiting a file (in this case) sets the major mode. I've reworded that.

Answer (score 3):

You've been mislead by the unusual terminology in Emacs Lisp. A *[buffer-local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal.html)* is not a local variable! It's a global variable which has (potentially) different values in every buffer. “Buffer-local variable” is a shortcut for “variable with buffer-local bindings”. A buffer-local variable doesn't have to be global, but it usually is.

The macro `setq-local` sets the *buffer-local value* of the specified *global* variable. To set the value of a local variable, call `setq`.

Comment: To expand slightly on this crucial point, the main difference between CL and EL is not the kind of thing that differentiates, say, Scheme or Clojure (Lisp-1, TCO, immutability, etc); it's that EL has one concept that is alien to all other Lisps, that of a *default data structure* -- when nothing else is specified, the default in EL is to operate on the current buffer. Buffer-local variables are one of the artifacts of this architecture.